# What is the correct way to place this JAR in my local repo?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  Evidently, the Oracle JDBC drivers are not available in a public Maven repo, so I'm reduced to installing it to my local one.  So I created this file

```
~/.m2/repository/oracle/oracle/10.2.0.3.0/classes12.jar
```

I have this in my pom.xml file …

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>classes12</artifactId>
  <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Yet upon running maven, I'm getting this error.  How do I structure my local repo? - Dave

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project infinitiusa_leads_testing: Could not resolve dependencies for project infinitiusa_leads_testing:infinitiusa_leads_testing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find oracle:classes12:jar:10.2.0.3.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must **install** the file in the repository, not only copy it to the right directory. See the answer: [Find Oracle JDBC driver in Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository).

Secondly, the directory is actually not right. For the dependency you provided in pom.xml it should lie in:

```
~/.m2/repository/oracle/classes12/10.2.0.3.0/classes12-10.2.0.3.0.jar
```

But this is taken care of by `install:install-file`, don't manipulate the repository directory manually (except deleting some stuff, maven sometimes gets confused and it needs *restart*, but that's a different story).

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=oracle -DartifactId=classes12 \
 -Dversion=10.2.0.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=classes12.jar
```

BTW consider `com.oracle` as `groupId`.

Also maven typically gives the very exact command line you should run to install the missing dependency in your local repository. Don't know why it didn't happen in your case.