# Adding odbc14.jar manually to Spring Roo project

Tags: maven, spring-roo, spring-jdbc

I am getting error as

"Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4"

in pom.xml when i entered command,

jpa setup --provider ECLIPSELINK --database ORACLE

I googled and found out that

"oracle jar cannot be added automatically, as of now. we have to configure it manually."

Can i maven dependency related jar manually to project? If yes, How?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898499/oracle-jdbc-ojdbc6-jar-as-a-maven-dependency

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually install the [driver from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html).

In command prompt install the driver to Maven's local repository using [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html).

```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your_ojdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=oracle -Dversion=10.2.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Now you add the dependency to the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```