# Maven cannot resolve dependencies for my project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

For the past couple days, I have been stuck on this problem to no avail. I have a couple dependencies described in my pom.xml. But Eclipse screams an error at me saying "Could no resolve dependencies for project"

I have the details below.

*pom.xml*

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>edi</groupId>
<artifactId>edi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts-menu</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-menu</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>WEB-INF/src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
         <directory>WEB-INF/src</directory>
         <excludes>
           <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
         </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <webXml>WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

*Maven log:*

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------   --
[INFO] Building edi 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ojdbc6-  11.2.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------  --
[INFO] Total time: 22.486s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 30 10:41:56 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/118M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project edi: Could not resolve dependencies   for project edi:edi:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for    [com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0 (compile), commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6   (compile), commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 (compile), struts-menu:struts-  menu:jar:2.4.3 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0: Could not transfer artifact   com.oracle:ojdbc6:pom:11.2.0 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I do not see "com.oracle:ojdbc6" at Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.oracle%22

Comment: As SiKing says the ojdbc6 jar is not available in maven central. You'll need to download and install it to your local repository manually. See following questions for details:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9898499/1570834 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1074869/1570834

Comment: It worked. No Oracle jars are in Maven due to some license. Once I removed that portion. It worked. Thanks for your help anyways guys.