# Import maven dependency in .m2 folder using filename without version

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a file named ojdbc6.jar in my .m2/oracle... folder. For my project I need maven to look for the file name only, like ojdbc6.jar. I have realised that Maven forces the search for a file named ojdbc6-{version}.jar and I can't find a way to make maven search for the filename without the version.
Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) might help how to do it.

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898499/oracle-jdbc-ojdbc6-jar-as-a-maven-dependency) is even better.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is the old way I was doing. I would like to have all dependencies in pom without this workaround.

Comment: But install-file is the best you can do, then you add this dependency in pom. Your way is almost the same (you copy the file to .m2) but the drawback is that you do it not in the maven way, so maven can't find it.

Comment: When I do ujulu's solution, the file is installed in m2 folder with the version appended to the filename (ojdbc-{version}.jar). As krzyk said, probably it's not possible to make maven find the filename without the version appended to it because it's not the maven pattern. Thank you for your help.