# Maven ojdbc configuration error

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies

So I have a project and I try to build it with Maven. One of my dependencies is this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have the Oracle driver installed and I also have it in my local repo. I made sure to put it there manually. And still when I want to build my project I get this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bla: Could not resolve dependencies for project dbla:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Does anybody have any idea why? Do I have to check somewhere else or did I miss something?

Comment: can you Show the structure in your local repo? Where you define the Version of the artifact?

Comment: clean your `.m2` folder and force maven to download again all dependencies of **main** `pom.xml`!! if not, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved

Answer (score 0):

Ojdbc6 driver is not in a public maven repository. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898499/oracle-jdbc-ojdbc6-jar-as-a-maven-dependency).

If you can use Ojdbc7, it [was recently added](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for) by Oracle to maven public repository, so you can have a try.