# Maven Install errors

Tags: maven

I am using below link to resolve  the maven-ojdbc issue and I am unable to add ojdbc6.jar to local repo.
[Oracle JDBC ojdbc6 Jar as a Maven Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898499/oracle-jdbc-ojdbc6-jar-as-a-maven-dependency)

Step 1 mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/ojdbc6.jar -DgeneratePom=true

The build fails @ step 1. I have apache-maven-3.3.9 installed. It works fine when I test it with mvn -version. When I execute below it is trying to download
maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom. and build fails with message https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Permission denied: connect

I downloaded this jar from MAVEN site and dropped in the folder apache-maven-3.3.9\lib. When I run the build it fails again trying to download the below files. I downloaded and added all the below to  apache-maven-3.3.9\lib  folder.

> maven-plugin-api-2.2.1.jar, maven-settings-2.2.1.jar
>   maven-profile-2.2.1.jar, maven-project-2.2.1.jar,
>   maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar

Then I noticed that there are duplicates of above files but with 3.3.9 version. The mvn install still fails. I am not sure what the issue is? Can somebody guide me.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.maven.setting s.RuntimeInfo.(Ljava/io/File;)V
>           at org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter.(SettingsAdapter.jav
>   a:60)
>           at org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession.(MavenSession.java:311)
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:187)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
> ```
>
> java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
>   cher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
>   a:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
>   uncher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
>   356)

Comment: does maven work proper when you call `mvn clean package` for a simple demo project?

Comment: does `<Home>/.m2/settings.xml` contain correct proxy settings? (if you're using one)

Comment: I cd to my maven project that I build in eclipse and called the command mvn clean. It is still trying to download maven-plugin-api-2.2.1 jar         and I get the error downloadinghttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.2.1/maven-plugin-api-2.2.1.jar    https://repo.maven.apache.org:443:                 Permission denied: connect. There is no settings.xml under <HOME>/.m2/.

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: "Use a proxy server for your LAN” option is unchecked.

Comment: no no ... what I mean is: do you connect to the internet via proxy?

Comment: No. I just found out one more thing. If I use maven inside eclipse Luna . I am able to run maven clean and maven package. The embedded version is 3.2.1. I change directory to my project in command prompt and if I run mvn clean or mvn  package it fails.  The version I have on my machine is 3.3.9. My classpath is set to 3.3.9/bin

Comment: does _classpath_ contain `3.3.9/bin` or is it in _PATH_ ?