# maven dependency or jar for oracle.forms.handler.IHandler?

Tags: java, import

I have searched everywhere on the internet to find a jar or maven dependency for `import oracle.forms.handler.IHandler;
import oracle.forms.properties.ID;
import oracle.forms.ui.CustomEvent;
import oracle.forms.ui.VBean;` but until now can't find it.

**Anybody knows how to fix this import in my code?**

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven Repositories cannot distribute oracle libraries due to proprietary license restrictions.  You will need to first go get the jars from oracle.com (the forms library comes with something called 'Oracle Fusion Middleware' which could be a good place to start).  Once you can isolate the jar files, you can add them to your local maven repository using the [mvn install:install-file](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) command.  Using the group/artifact ids you define in said command, add the dependency to your pom file. maven will then be able to import the jar from the local repository and should resolve your eclipse build path issues for you.

Comment: In the  Oracle website there is no download for Oracle Fusion Middleware. where can i download it?