# Manually downloaded Oracle driver but still getting Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3:compile

Tags: eclipse, maven, driver, m2eclipse

I have followed as mentioned in this article [Find Oracle JDBC driver in Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository).

I have manually downloaded Oracle driver to `maven\repo\com\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.3` and added the following in pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

However I am still getting the following error

```
Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3:compile
```

What I am doing wrong and how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install it in your repository using mvn install:install-file ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes I did and after running that I have the following files in the same directory where I have copied jar file. `1) ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar.lastUpdated 2) ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.pom 3) _maven.repositories`

Comment: Maybe that helps: Rightclick on your project -> Maven -> Update Project...

Comment: I do not have `Update Project`, instead I have `Update Dependencies, Update Snapshots and Update Project Configuration` I tried all those but same error still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue can be resolved by doing the following steps

- Run the below from the folder where `ojdbc6.jar` is copied

  `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.
    oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar
    -DgeneratePom=true`
- Run the below from workspace

  `mvn -U clean`