# Application tests can connect to and query database but Maven can't load driver

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Spring MVC app has Oracle and Hibernate properties in a file like this (persistence-oracle.properties):

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=[Database URL]
jdbc.user=[Username]
jdbc.pass=[Password]

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
#hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

And while the tests show that the app can connect to and query the database and get data back, when I try to package it with maven, I get this error:

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

The reason the properties are in this properties file and not hibernate.cfg.xml is because configuration is done via Spring Java Configuration similar to [step 3 here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/hibernate-4-with-spring.html)

Why can't Maven find the driver while Spring can?

**Edit1: Oracle dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Show us your dependency for oracle's driver and post your source folder configuration

Comment: It's very likely you have the scope set to **test** on that dependency

Comment: I didn't even have an Oracle dependency in Maven. When I add it as in the Edit, Eclipse shows this error though, "Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3"

Comment: So the way it was explained to me is that I only need the oracle driver jar at compile time because the application server will have its own. So, I can add a <scope>compile</scope> to the oracle dependency so that Maven can build and so that there won't be conflicts between 2 jars at runtime (1 from Maven and 1 from app server)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to mention the oracle driver in the build path? if so, I think it could be the license issue see here [Find Oracle JDBC driver in Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository)

Answer (score 0):

The ojdbc6 dependency what you are looking in the mvnrepo is not exact. One should add the collection tag for ojdbc6 verison dependency to get the jars dumped into your path.