# Cannot find oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory in Oracle ucp

Tags: java, oracle, connection-pooling, pool, ucp

I want to create Oracle UCP using this code:

```
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;

System.out.println("***** OracleDS_UCP -> start init of PoolDataSource");

            PoolDataSource pool = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
            pool.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
            pool.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE");
            pool.setUser("test");
            pool.setPassword("test");
            pool.setMaxStatements(10); // the maximum number of statements that may be pooled or cached on a connection.
            pool.setInitialPoolSize(2);
            pool.setMinPoolSize(1);
            pool.setMaxPoolSize(50);
            pool.setLoginTimeout(60); // one minute
            pool.setConnectionWaitTimeout(60); // one minute
            pool.setAbandonedConnectionTimeout(30 * 60); // thirty minutes
            pool.setMaxIdleTime(60 * 60); // one hour and kill inactive or idle connections
            pool.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(60 * 60); // one hour and kill inactive or idle connections
            pool.setConnectionWaitTimeout(0); // do not wait for a used connection to be released by a client.
            pool.setConnectionHarvestTriggerCount(40);
            pool.setConnectionHarvestMaxCount(10);
```

I'm using

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Embed-Dependency>ucp,ojdbc6</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.osgi.framework,
                        javax.sql,
                        javax.naming,
                        oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource,
                        oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory,
                        oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl,
                        javax.naming.spi,
                        javax.management,
                        javax.management.modelmbean,
                        oracle.jdbc.pool
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Include-Resource>
                        ucp-11.2.0.3.jar,
                        ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar
                    </Include-Resource>
                    <Bundle-ClassPath>
                        ucp-11.2.0.3.jar,
                        ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar,
                        .
                    </Bundle-ClassPath>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Activator>org.test.ucp.activator.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But when I start the code in a standalone bundle I get this error message:

```
    Test Oracle UCP
ERROR: Bundle ucpTest [21] Error starting inputstream:ucpTest-1.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleExce
ption: Activator start error in bundle ucpTest [21].)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface oracle.ucp.jdbc.LabelableConnection is not visible fro
m class loader
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.ConnectionProxyFactory.createConnectionProxy(ConnectionProxyFactory
.java:78)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:919)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:863)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:855)
        at org.test.osgi.ucp.impl.OracleDS_UCP.getConnection(OracleDS_UCP.java:26)
        at org.test.ucp.activator.Activator.testOracleUCP(Activator.java:41)
        at org.test.ucp.activator.Activator.start(Activator.java:17)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1977)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Maybe I'm not configured the UCP correctly. Can you help to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace of the exception you are getting? Is this a web/enterprise application or a standalone application?

Comment: Post updated. This is a standalone application.

Comment: Include LabelableConnection in pom.xml

Comment: I already done it but with no result.

Comment: Please check for conflicting/missing `ucp.jar` in `CLASSPATH` configured for building Maven plugin.

Comment: yes, it's missing. Can you show me some configuration that I need to add?

Comment: Please review [this question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository). I hope that help you to sucessfully resolve a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, I have not worked on UCP. Hence I may not be able to give you a full solution but few hints:

1. Try using Apache Commons DBCP available as [OSGi bundle](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.servicemix.bundles%22%20AND%20a%3A%22org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp%22).
2. Try removing the Import-Package directive from your BND configuration. BND is intelligent to identify this. Then possible refine your imports later on.
3. Try putting a [DynamicImport-Package](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/DynamicImport-Package): * directive to your BND configuration.:

   <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>

Try the above steps, and possible combine 2 & 3 above, and report back if this works.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have put together a small demo application quickly with bundles driver, ucp and the client code, all separately as a Maven project at  http://static.ethomasjoseph.com/osgi-project.zip Let me know if this would help.

Comment: Could you please investigate this?

Comment: Hi Peter, I investigated a bit on this (based on your pastebin code). The real issue here is at runtime, the OracleDriver is still not visible to the UCP. We may have to bridge this. Since the source code for UCP is not available readily, debugging is a bit messy. In the past often I have patched the library with my own, where the "dynamic" driver lookup happens.

Comment: So there is no solution?

Comment: The solution is to find the code where the driver class lookup happens, and ensure that UCP is able to find the driver. If you can point me to that class, it would help me to give you a fix quicker.

Comment: Did you had any chance to test this?