# Configure classpath for external jars

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I would like to configure external jars into java classpath. Is there any way to configure this into Apache Felix configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

You can start felix with:

```
java -jar felix.jar
```

You can use add other jars to the classpath to this start command as for any other jars:

```
java -cp classpathJars -jar felix.jar
```

When you are done, you should visit the documentation of felix configuration: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html

Check the documentation of the following property: *org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra*

Notes.: We hav not had a project till now in which we had to do such trick. In case this is the only solution, you might want to think of:

- Adding OSGi manifest headers to the jars and use them as OSGi bundles
- Leaving that technology out from your stack

Comment: Here is the main problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699182/cannot-find-oracle-ucp-jdbc-pooldatasourcefactory-in-oracle-ucp   I can provide you sample jar if you want to try to solve this problem.