# dependency issue for net unicorn and ojdbc14

Tags: java, oracle, maven

Here i am facing some issue with the following jar files

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.unicon</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-password-manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

net.unicon:cas-password-manager:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Missing POM for com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:11.2.0.3
[WARNING] Missing POM for net.tanesha.recaptcha4j:recaptcha4j:jar:0.0.8
[WARNING] Missing POM for net.tanesha.recaptcha4j:recaptcha4j:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

can anyone help me out by sending the correct maven dependency ....

Comment: Are you talking about this https://github.com/Unicon/cas-password-manager?

Comment: but for me the link is going to sonatype/net/unicorn

Comment: can you plz help me out with the right maven dependency

Comment: Question is not clear too much which dependency you are looking as ur Waring message saying missing dependency for com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:11.2.0.3 and other are you looking for these ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository

Comment: yes i am looking mainly for those 4 dependency

Comment: 1.cas-password-manager:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT     2.com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:11.2.0.3    3.net.tanesha.recaptcha4j:recaptcha4j:jar:0.0.8  4.net.tanesha.recaptcha4j:recaptcha4j:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT