# Unable to resolve maven dependency; executable jar isn't getting downloaded

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-dependency-plugin

Using Eclipse Kepler, I created a new Maven project. Later I tried adding 2 libraries by right-clicking the project folder -> Maven -> Add dependency. Subsequently, the code below got added to the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>rowset</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I tried to build the project, I got the below error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project *********: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.*****.*******:war:1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:rowset:jar:1.0.1, ojdbc:ojdbc:jar:14: Failure to find javax.sql:rowset:jar:1.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

On further investigation I found that, in my local maven repository (m2) the executable jars for the mentioned libraries were missing. I even tried 'Force Update' as suggested in the error message by right-clicking the project folder -> Maven -> Force Update of Snapshots/Releases, but this didn't help either.

Could any expert please suggest?

Comment: Due to licence problems, you won't find a legal ojdbc driver in a public maven repository. For more details:  [Find Oracle JDBC driver in Maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository)

Comment: Marked as duplicate: Same problem, different driver version.

Comment: @stuXnet: That applies to the first dependency added. How about the second dependency?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, I am trying to execute the code in my office system, which connects to internet through a proxy server. Is there any way to include the proxy server details, if at all this is needed?