# Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc5:jar:11.2.0.1 error in pom.xml in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven, jar

I have created a project in Eclipse using maven. I am getting an error in my pom.xml in dependency, the dependency look like this.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am getting:

> Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc5:jar:11.2.0.1

I saw a solution in stackoverflow it self, That-

> due to Oracle license restriction, there are no public
>    repositories that provide ojdbc jar.
>    you need to download it and install in your local repository. 
>    Get jar from Oracle and install it in your local maven repository using

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={path/to/your/ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

the above command. I executed the bellow command changing the path to my ojdbc.jar.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={
C/monitoring-workspace/ojdbc5.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc5 -Dversion=11.2.0.1-Dpackaging=jar
```

but I am getting an error on cmd that [image]

**I am confused in two things**

- My oracle folder it self has ojdbc5 and ojdbc6 jar then why do I need
  to install ojdbc5
- What should be the path I need to provide while installing ojdbc-the
  where I need to install or the path where I have kept ojdbc5 jar.

Comment: Three things here (at least): 1) remove the "{". 2) When copy-pasting, do not include new line in your command. 3) Path should at least include _C:/_ instead of _C/_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Oracle JDBC driver in Maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository)

Answer (score 2):

I see you have referred to [mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/) article. The problem is new lines. You have to make sure that you got it in one line in the command prompt.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:/monitoring-workspace/ojdbc5.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc5 -Dversion=11.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: after executing the above command I am getting 
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[ERROR] The specified file 'C:\monitoring-workspace\ojdbc5.jar' not exists
[INFO] 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.260 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-17T14:34:11+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/152M
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on p

Comment: -Dfile= do ineed to provide my workspace path?? or the path of the jar file. please reply

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in the reply. you should provide the path to the ojdbc jar

Comment: and also consider using ojdbc6, instead of 5 if there is no particular reason to use 5

Answer (score 1):

ojdbc6.jar - Classes for use with JDK 1.6. or newer
 
ojdbc5.jar - Classes for use with JDK 1.5.
 
you need only one of them