# Oracle Driver Error oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdbc

I'm using the `ojdbc7.jar` that is distributed from the Oracle site, and so far it has worked perfectly.  Recently, however, we've decided to switch to using a maven structure for our webapp development so I've been converting our Java Web App to maven.  Now I'm seeing this `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z` error when making an Oracle DB connection even though I'm using the exact same driver file as I was in my non-maven build.  I have the dependency declared like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have manually installed the driver using Netbeans, as the maven depository does not contain the ojdbc7 driver.

Why am I seeing this error and what can I do about it?  It's clearly a maven related problem seeing as this builds perfectly without maven managing it.

Stack Trace:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:913)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:226)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:302)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2208)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2191)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1945)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)

com.networkfleet.sre.common.db.Resource.getDBConnectionDEV(Resource.java:75)

com.networkfleet.sre.app.checkreport.CheckReportSrv.doGet(CheckReportSrv.java:63)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)

org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)

org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)

org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)

org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)

org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)

org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: **did u upgrade Java**? Which version u was using before mavenized ur web app & now which version u r using?

Comment: Would you mind to post the complete stack trace?

Comment: We're using Java 1.7, and yes, I'll post the stack trace in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You need run maven  install-file since maven can't download it.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository/1074971#1074971e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository/1074971#1074971)

Comment: I did this already, it does not work. I still get the same error, and only when I use Maven.