# How to install ojdbc6 jar on linux maven local repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[Error: Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdnPH.png)

> Error shows: Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3

all `groupId`,`Version`, `artifactId` is correct
in my project this dependency is not works and i was also try to copy jar on local `.m2` oracle maven repo but ,this is not still working. how to resolve this kind of errors?

Answer (score -1):

add the dependency for it in your pom.xml and when you will do `mvn clean install` it will do that for you
 Use the below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>cn.guoyukun.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>oracle-ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
```

Comment: And it has nothing to do with your OS maven behaves uniformly evrywhere :)

Comment: This will gives this type of [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mavenhiber: Could not resolve dependencies for project mavenhiber:mavenhiber:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: @sujitshelar @KulbhushanSingh There is no `cn.guoyukun.jdbc:oracle-ojdbc6` on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|oracle-ojdbc6). And if it were it'd apparently be a copyright infringement. Did you follow the link given in the first comment to the question?

Comment: i have copied the dependency from maven only, still it could be copyright infringement? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.guoyukun.jdbc/oracle-ojdbc6/11.2.0.3.0

Comment: Maybe not if you don't re-publish it somewhere else. Another serious topic is whether you trust http://www.guoyukun.cn/ enough to use a library which apparently has been re-published by them illegally and of which you (and me) don't know whether it has been tampered with or not.

Comment: true.. thanks Gerold

Answer (score -1):

Copying only the jar to local repo will not help unless you also copy the related pom files. Maven is caching files and if the file was not accessible (e.g. no internet, wrong proxy settings, etc.), maven still remembers it. So remove the cached files (remove whole the particular folder from your .m2 repo) and try to build again. If you have the connection correct and you have also defined the repository where to download the file from, you should be fine.

I'm not sure if this jar file is in maven central, try to add this to your pom.xml or maven settings file.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>codelds</id>
      <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Comment: Cited from the link of the first comment to the question:  "_Is that lds.org repository legal? According to this answer it is illegal: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1074971/1415732_" – "_Of course it's "better" to add some arbitrary repo to your project, yeah. Wow, this is wrong on so many levels_".