# Spring Boot application The url cannot be null

Tags: spring, oracle, maven

Hello when i trying start Spring Boot app a get a stacktrace

```
2016-11-18 04:41:35.492  WARN 4256 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
2016-11-18 04:41:35.499 ERROR 4256 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:308) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:716) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:648) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
```

I added url in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:spring
```

I think it's may be problem with drivers to oracle, maven can't find this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So I just add external jar to my project, but i still have problem with wrong url

Comment: one cannot really reproduce the issue with the information you've given. Try a minimal test example.

Answer (score 3):

```
Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
```

You might also want to resolve that by adding a driver class name to your properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Are you configuring a DataSource bean somewhere within your application? Assuming you haven't disabled auto configuration you should be able to get a valid datasource configuration.

Comment: Thank you i added but i still this same problem. I didin't have DataSource bean i just add POJO class with JPA annotation i set hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop and i hopes it's enaugh to create tables in database

Comment: Hmm. When you run the Spring Boot application is it definitely picking up the properties file? Are there any other properties configured than you know are working?

Comment: No I'm not sure, i have just database configuration, but application.properties is in default localization

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle JDBC driver has only been a part of maven from V 11.2.0.4.. had some issues with it in the past.

Follow the link "https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for" to download and add the driver you want to the local maven repo.

Also check [Find Oracle JDBC driver in Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository)

Please make sure you have specified and included the relevant database vendor dependency in your pom. If not, you might also experience the same error message.