# Warning: Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null, in springboot working with two datasources

Tags: spring-boot

I have currently configured spring boot to work with two different datasources. The application is working fine, however when I start the spring boot application I get an warning repeated 10 times like below:

> 2018-06-05 10:28:15.897  WARN 8496 --- [r://myScheduler] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.

As I mentioned this is not affecting my application, but I would like to know why I am having this kind of warning and if there is any way to fix it.

Comment: Maybe this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655360/ddg#40655527

Answer (score 8):

When using two or more datasources you need to configure them yourself. In that case Spring Boot's DataSourceAutoConfiguration (and also DataSourceProperties) won't be used.

You most probably have the related DB details like the name of the JDBC driver class name in application.properties file as follows:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

primary.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.yyy.zzz.www:1433;databaseName=primaryDB
primary.datasource.username=username
primary.datasource.password=password

other.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.yyy.zzz.www:1433;databaseName=otherDb
other.datasource.username=otheruser
other.datasource.password=otherpassword
```

Thus, to set the driver class name for the datasource just say:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
String driverClassName;

@Primary
@Bean(name = "primaryDb")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(driverClassName).build();
}

@Bean(name = "otherDb")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "other.datasource")
public DataSource otherDataSource() {
    return  DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(driverClassName).build();
}
```