# Java: How to get the jdbc oracle driver after download by user?

Tags: java

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074971/5333804) and looking through the [license agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/distribution-license-152002.html) for the oracle driver it sounds like we have to ensure that our users accept the contents of the license agreement? From the license agreement:

> (...)You will have a written agreement with Your Contractor(s) that strictly limits their right to use the Programs and that otherwise protects Oracle’s intellectual property rights to the same extent as this Agreement.(...)

A way to ensure that all users have accepted the contents of the agreement would be to require our users to download the odbc driver separately. Our application will be distributed as a jar, so we need to ask the user for the path to the driver jar that they have downloaded and use that. We won't be able to add the driver jar to the maven repository and include the dependency because the user will download the jar themselves. Is there a way to import the driver jar and use it's contents after our application has already been started?

Or would we be forced to add an installation step to our application where the final application jar will be compiled after indicating the path to the driver?

Alternatively, have we misunderstood the license agreement?

Comment: This is off-topic, we are not lawyers and this is not strictly a programming problem. You will only get opinions, and you will have no way of knowing if those opinions are correct or not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The program specific question here is wether it's possible to import the jar in our code after the user has downloaded it separately. The rest is just context as to why we would want to do this.

Comment: Is this a web application ? What JRE version is required ? Do you include the JRE with your application or the user must provide one ?

Comment: @RealHowTo This is a desktop application. A distributed jar given to the people who will need it. The user must provide JRE.

Comment: Unlike JRE extensions, a (pure) JDBC driver is just a jar that 'happens' to provide a common SPI and whose manifest can register it. Just **have it on the CLASSPATH**, either by putting it in or moving it to somewhere already on the CLASSPATH, or by changing the CLASSPATH to include where it is. (A native driver, which this isn't, requires the *library* path as well.)