# Unable to load local jar inside my jar

Tags: java, maven, jboss6.x, jbossfuse, ojdbc

I am banging my head around this, but could not find any solution.
I am using **jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379** server and deploying my jar inside Jboss_home/deploy/ folder

The problem I am having is that I am unable to load the oracle ojdbc jar when I run my application. I have tried adding this ojdbc14.jar in my local repository and then adding dependency in POM like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It successfully resolves the imports problem, but when I deploy my jar in Jboss and run my application, it gives an error that:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:port/some_name

I have also tried adding ojdbc.jar like this in POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

but still getting the same "No suitable driver found" message.
Any help how can I add the ojdbc.jar inside my jar ?

**** Update ****

Java Code:

```
try
   {
   //   File CP_file = new File("/home/path/to/ojdbc14.jar");
   //   DBFactory dbMethod = new DBFactory();
   //   dbMethod.addJarToClasspath(CP_file);

      Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
      String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:port/name";
      String userID = "userid";
      String password = "pass";

  //  dbMethod.isJarOnClassPath(CP_file);

      Connection dbConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,userID,password);
// getting exception on above line
```

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Configuring_and_Running_Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/files/ESBRuntimeFailoverJdbc.html

Comment: I assume the jar is on the classpath, and the service has been restarted? Can you just try running `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` anywhere before your first connection attempt? This should _hopefully_ create a new instance of the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have same proplem and i solve it

put this repository in your pom file

```
   <repository>
       <id>codelds</id>
       <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
```

Then add your dependency

```
 <!-- ORACLE JDBC driver, need install yourself -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a JAR inside your bundle using [Maven Bundle Plugin](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).
This will also take care of adding correct OSGi headers in your manifest.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Embed-Dependency>ojdbc6</Embed-Dependency>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Anyway this is not a good approach. I would recommend using either JPA or adding Oracle JDBC drivers to the `lib/` folder and exporting them through the system bundle.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `system`-scoped dependency in `pom.xml`, the jar file of the dependency is not packaged into your binary file. In other words, the jar is not on the classpath.

1. Try to use the `provided`-scope of Maven. Then the odbc-jar must be in some lib folder of JBoss, similar to the lib-folder like in Tomcat.
2. You could to `install` the odbc-jar into your local Maven repository and then include the dependency with default-scope.
3. If your scenario is, that the jar is not deployable, because it `must` be placed on a specific path in the file system, I would try to add the jar-File to classpath during runtime. In another context than yours, I was able to deploy and run my lib with the following snippet.

Until you find something better, it hopefully serves as a work-around:

```
private boolean addJarToClasspath( File jarFile )
{
    try
    {
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Class<?> urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
        Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod( "addURL", new Class<?>[] { URL.class } );
        method.setAccessible( true );
        method.invoke( urlClassLoader, new Object[] { jarFile.toURI().toURL() } );
        System.out.println( jarFile.getAbsolutePath() + " dynamically added to classpath" );
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isJarOnClassPath( File jarFile )
{
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    URL[] urls = urlClassLoader.getURLs();
    for ( URL url : urls )
    {
        File file = new File( url.getFile() );
        if ( file.getPath().endsWith( jarFile.getName() ) )
        {
            System.out.println( jarFile.getAbsolutePath() + " is on classpath" );
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please see the instructions for [mvn install:install-file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1074971) for the second approach, which I strongly recommend. This is the Maven-way to deal with third-party libs which are not provided by public repos. 

Only if that does really not work, we should talk about the third one, which is actually a bad work-around. But really only then.

Comment: Perhaps also a useful info by Oracle itself: [Get Oracle JDBC drivers from the Oracle Maven Repository - NetBeans, Eclipse & Intellij](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for)

Answer (score 0):

you can use wrap protocol to install in karaf

```
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:groupid/artifactid/version
```