# How can i access OJDBC driver into Liferay 7 Gradle module

Tags: build.gradle, liferay-7, ojdbc

I want to know Accessing Oracle DB from Liferay 7 CE Gradle Project is possible?
As I am working on such portlet,
I have created Spring MVC Portlet and Added Oracle DB Connection and Other aceess related code and tried adding dependency of Oracle JDBC Driver in build.gradle of project as "compile group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc14', version: '10.2.0.2.0'",
On "Gradle refresh" in eclipse it doesn't show any error.
But I could not able to build project, It Unable to resolve dependency.

Shows Error as below.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':wars:tp-XXXXXX-Portlet:compileClasspath'.

  > Could not find ojdbc14.jar (com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.2.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.2.0/ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar

Is there any specific version of Oracle supports in such scenario Or How can i achieve such requirement.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note that 10.2.0.2 is an unsupported version. We do have this for a download on [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) page. We always recommend you to use the latest JDBC driver and definitely not the unsupported version.

After downloading the right JDBC driver, you will have to manually add it to the repository. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I got below solution and it worked for me.

Done entry in build.gradle dependencies as follows.

compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '**/*.jar')

And I have used manually downloaded **ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar** and kept it into **WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar**

Here lib folder is created manually.