# Oracle JDBC Driver » 10.2.0.2.0 gives page not found

Tags: oracle, maven

I am not getting any dependency for ORACLE JDBC driver from maven repo. Please help.

Comment: Simple answer: You will never get it cause you have to download it manually from Oracle...

Comment: Then how can I set it on my maven pom while running CI? I am not going to place this everywhere I run my suite.

Comment: You should start using a repository or hopefully you already using one...

Comment: You have to add the repository, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598253/7677308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either follow the [advise of SilverNak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598253/2129801) and add the Oracle repository. Or you simply download the JDBC jar manually and add it to your local Maven repository as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074971/2129801):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-your-downloaded-jar> -DgroupId=com.oracle 
    -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```