# @autowired issue with jdbctemplate in spring boot latest version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oracle11g, jdbctemplate

Below is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc:1512:dbq
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Below is my POM.xml

```
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
      </parent>
    <dependencies>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency> 

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency> 

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
            </dependency>

      </dependencies>
```

I have created new maven + Spring boot with latest version project using eclipse. But getting below error when try to autowired JdbcTemplate. I have share my properties file and pom.xml above.

```
    Error::
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'asurintApp': Unsatisfied dependency 
    expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Ill`enter code here`egalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: If you use spring-boot then it is better to use JPA.

Comment: when I add dependency"<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>"  instead of "spring-boot-starter-jdbc" then getting Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration.

Comment: `Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` -> you are missing `ojdbc` dependency

Comment: Added : <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0</version>
        </dependency> BUT getting same error

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency> Try adding this dependency

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the jdbc driver for the Oracle database.

Unfortunately due the binary license there is no public repository with the Oracle Driver JAR. Try to add it to you pom following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository#1074971).

Comment: Thank you, it's working for me. But why external jar required for jdbctemplate?

Comment: The jdbctemplate actually would allow you to access a range of realtional databases using the same interface., but for each different database you would need a new driver. The oracle drivers are in the external jar and will be used by jdbc. Unfortunately these drivers are not open source and thus due to the licence it is necessary to jump through some hoops.

Answer (score 0):

I add this to show another way to store `jar` in `spring-boot` app. This way if new developer pull this application he/she will not need to follw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository#1074971) way.

Make a dir `lib` inside `src`  :  `src/lib/`

then put your `ojdbc-{versio}.jar` in `lib` folder and then add this dependency in `gradle`:

```
compile files('src/lib/ojdbc8-{version}.jar')
```

for maven add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
groupId ...
artifactId ...
version ...
<scope>system</scope
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How is an Gradle related answer going to help the OP who is using Maven?

Comment: i add that for someone who use gradle

Comment: added dependency for maven

Comment: That won't work for Maven as `system` scoped dependencies won't be included in the created artifact. So it will work in the IDE (depending on the IDE) but not for the runtime artifact.