# How do we configure a maven oracle dependency when we are using a docker-compose file?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, docker-compose, pom.xml

I am using a docker-compose file to run my docker containers and I have this image for my oracle database.

```
oracle-12c:
    image: overclockedpixel/oracle12c
    ports:
        - '1521:1521'
    container_name: db_local
```

I am making a Java Maven project and I need to to set my dependency in my pom.xml file as such

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
   <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But since I didn't install any ojdbc because I'm using the docker image, I get this error

> Cannot resolve com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.4.0

How should I configure this in order to get my dependency resolved?

Comment: I think you have a wrong groupId ... check this: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.oracle%20AND%20a:ojdbc14%20AND%20v:10.2.0.4.0 furthermore the dependency you are showing is not the one which is causing the issue...

Comment: Maybe this question related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584499/problems-trying-to-install-ojdbc7-as-a-maven-dependency