# JOOQ Setup Oracle with Maven Code Generation

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, jooq

I am trying to setup an Oracle database with JOOQ on Maven for Code Generation.
Currently trying to connect with Oracle Database JDBC.

https://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/

The following example from resource is Postgresql. What is the syntax for Dependencies for Oracle setup?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1212</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: A list is maintained [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html) where you can follow the links to see the group, artifact and version information. There are also some notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35436041/12567365) which may help. Or look directly in Maven, [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of ojdbc are now on Maven Central, too, e.g.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
  <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[Please refer to Oracle's documentation for more information](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html).